# How to prevent a form from being resubmitted on Jquery Submit Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form and jquery submit event on it with an ajax call. After i click submit this form is getting resubmitted. I don't want to disable the button just don't want it to resubmit the form. Tried adding "return false" after the submit event but it didn't work

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
$(".bmlf-form").on("submit", event => {     

    event.preventDefault();
    const values = $(event.target).serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: `apiURL`,
        type: 'Post',
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        datatype: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(objectifyForm(values)),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Thank you");
            $(".bmlf-form")[0].reset();

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Please try again");
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: well it should work so why is the code not being called? Is jQuery actually finding the form? Is the method being called?

Comment: I feel like this question is incomplete.  When do you not want the submit to happen again?  I assume if the ajax goes through the error method you would want to potentially allow them to submit again, no?

Comment: The method is getting called and everything is working, but once i click the submit button it's getting clicked once again. In other words multiple clicks are happening on the submit button. @epascarello

Comment: @Taplar yes exactly. If something goes wrong they should be able to rectify the error in the form and resubmit it. But once everything is good and i submit it, its getting submitted once and than immediately once again without me doing anything. Multiple submits on Submit button with only 1 click.

Comment: Then something else is going on.  From the code you have provided, a secondary submit would not happen.

Comment: Sounds like somehow you are binding it multiple times since there is no way that is doing it more than once. Look at the source code and see if somehow your code gets included multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
My form has a **"was-validated"** class that appends to the **"form"** element after initial submit request. So after the first submit click, validation is done and this class is appended to the form. As it's an ajax call the page is not reloaded and this class is still attached to my form which was again getting invoked and doing validation on form.

Solution is I Had to remove this class from the form once the event is success. I used the **.removeClass()** function of jquery and everything is good now.

On initial page load

```
   <form class="bmlf-form needs-validation" method="POST" novalidate="">
```

After submit button is clicked initially

```
<form class="bmlf-form needs-validation was-validated" method="POST" novalidate="">
```

jQuery Remove Class Code

```
  //some jQuery Code here
 success: function (data) {
            $(".bmlf-form").removeClass('was-validated');
            $(".bmlf-form")[0].reset();
            alert("Thank you");
        }
```